# How to specify a guid as row.names in R?

Tags: r, guid

Given a dataset  (stripped down for question)

```
id  activated   jobtitle    organisation    
11CE0982-B213-4140-B7FA-0000632D9B49    2013-05-30 06:40:00.000 NULL    Apple   
DFC75899-2335-48AC-BF30-00010AF58424    2014-05-29 23:47:55.807 Acting CIO  Care Connect
BC45E973-4AE4-4405-A62C-000373D2755C    2013-09-05 22:29:00.000 NULL        NULL
```

I can import the data file and make it into a data frame using

```
users_for_dashboard_view <- read.delim("/source/dashboard/users_for_dashboard_view.txt", na.strings="NULL")
users_for_dashboard_dataframe <- data.frame( users_for_dashboard_view, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

I want however to use the id field as the row.names
When I do this

```
users_for_dashboard_dataframe <- data.frame( users_for_dashboard_view, row.names = id, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

it fails with

```
Error in data.frame(users_for_dashboard_view, row.names = id, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()) : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
```

Every row has a guid in it.

What is the correct way to specify the id column with guids as row.names?

Comment: Try it with:`users_for_dashboard_dataframe <- data.frame( users_for_dashboard_view, row.names = users_for_dashboard_view$id, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())` maybe you have some other variable `id` in the variable space, for me your code works beside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data with your first attempt (no row.names=F)

```
users_for_dashboard_view <- read.delim("Neues Textdokument.txt", na.strings="NULL")
rownames(users_for_dashboard_view)<-users_for_dashboard_view$id
users_for_dashboard_view$id <- NULL
```